# Route 53 domain email account account creation without AWS workspace

Tags: php, email, amazon-route53, amazon-ses

I purchased a domain on route 53 and stood up a LAMP instance on AWS. I need my php running on my instance which I have associated to example.com to send emails.  I do not need to receive email, I just need outgoing email to go out through php from donotreply@example.com, but the php mail() doesn't won't with an AWS hosting configuration. I know I can use AWS workspace to create an email account like "forgotPassword@exapmle.com" but that has a monthly fee.

My question is whether there is a way to send an email from my AWS instance (Simple free tier linux).  For example can I create unix user named "dan" on linux, give it a password, and then dan@example.com will somehow get configured in SES to send emails?  I suspect not since the instance doesn't know its example.com...?

Other hosting environments I have used had this all pre-configured so I would really appreciate any guidance, even if it is just a link to the right documentation.  Success is having my php on AWS send an email, most likely through the SDK/API that is included as part of SES, but somehow getting mail() to just work would be even better!

Comment: you need a much boarder understanding of AWS